# Spring Security Multi Entry point with OAuth2

Tags: spring-security

Im trying to secure my spring boot application with multiple entry points depending on the user.

I have 3 types of authentication:

- Basic http username and password for system users
- OAuth for normal users
- Jwt after the user registered/logged in

The idea is to have the /register, /login and /token endpoints to be accessible after OAuth authentication.
For the system users, the /register, /login and /token endpoints are accessible only with username and password.
All other endpoints are only accessible with the JWT token obtained from the /login or /token endpoints.

For this I set up 3 WebSecurityConfigurer:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class BasicWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/system/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class OAuthWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/access/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@Order(3)
public class JwtWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();

        http
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is the OAuth configuration. It is not able to find the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google
```

I suppose that the antMatcher is hiding away the other endpoints?

Can someone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SecurityFilterChain` is what initiates the Authorization Request from `"/oauth2/authorization/google"`.

Since `"/oauth2/authorization/google"` doesn't match `"/api/v1/system/**"`,  `"/api/v1/access/**"` or `"/api/v1/**"`, the `SecurityFilterChain` is not called for that request, which means the Authorization Request is not initiated.

You can change the base URI used for authorization requests to match the path you've specified for the `SecurityFilterChain` (the default is `"/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}"`).

```java
http
    .antMatcher("/api/v1/access/**")
    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .authorizationEndpoint(ae -> ae
            .baseUri("/api/v1/access/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}")
        )
    );
```